# SharePoint workflow 2013 suspended

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

I have a 2013 workflow created in SharePoint Designer on a SharePoint site using FBA as login. When I create new item, the workflow is terminated immediately. At one point, the workflow starts but then it got suspended. This is the error displayed:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sliQ5.png

I found that for workflow errors related to authenticating request is usually related to User Profile Synchronization service, but for this server, that service is not running since the server is using SharePoint Active Directory Import in the Configure Synchronization Settings (instead of using SharePoint Profile Synchronization which needs to be selected to start the user profile sync service). Can anyone help please?

Notes:
Workflow can use app permission feature is turned on,
Workflow actions are wrapped in App Step, 
Already unticked the "Automatically update the workflow status to the current status" checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I logged this case to Microsoft and they found that in node 1, the Service Bus is running with version 1.1 while on node 2 is 1.0. Obviously, that could not work (although we're not sure what causes the version to mismatch) so we uninstalled Service Bus, Workflow Manager and related updates and fresh install everything under version 1.0, then upgrade to 1.1.

We still face workflow authentication issue after installation. Turns out we need to add the Workflow Manager Certificate into SharePoint trust store: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/governance/install-workflow-manager-certificates-in-sharepoint-server